# Flagging the first instance in an episode without transposing

Tags: sas

I'm working in SAS and I'm trying to create a column disease_flag that flags the first row where a given disease code occurs in an array. In this case the disease code I care about is 'A36'. Ideally I would like to do this without first transposing.

So say my data looks like this:

```
 episode_id diagcode1 diagcode2 diagcode3 
        121       A36       B11
        121       A36       B11       B12  
        121       B12       B05       B06 
        122       B12
        122       A36       B12       B13 
        122       B12       B01
        123       B12       B13       B11  
        123       B12       A36
        123       B13       B12
```

I want to add an additional column called disease_flag that flags the first instance of A36 in the array of columns diagcode1--diagcode3.

Thus the final output would look like this:

```
episode_id diagcode1 diagcode2 diagcode3 disease_flag
       121       A36       B11                    1
       121       A36       B11       B12          0
       121       B12       B05       B06          0
       122       B12                              0
       122       A36       B12       B13          1
       122       B12       B01                    0
       123       B12       B13       B11          0
       123       B12       A36                    1
       123       B13       B12                    0
```

Comment: Hi Deb and welcome.  This question would have been improved if you had included the code you'd written attempting to solve it, as we could have more easily given you advice on how to improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a retained helper variable which resets to 0 for each id and stays set to 1 from the first time A36 is found:

```
data have;
input episode_id diagcode1 $ diagcode2 $ diagcode3 $;
infile cards missover;
cards;
        121       A36       B11
        121       A36       B11       B12  
        121       B12       B05       B06 
        122       B12
        122       A36       B12       B13 
        122       B12       B01
        123       B12       B13       B11  
        123       B12       A36
        123       B13       B12
;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    by episode_id;
    retain t_flag;
    if first.episode_id then t_flag = 0;
    disease_flag = (diagcode1 = 'A36' or diagcode2 = 'A36' or diagcode3 = 'A36') and t_flag = 0;
    if disease_flag then t_flag = 1;
    drop t_flag;
run;
```

Comment: Ahhh, I was missing the retain line. Thank you for this solution, this is really helpful.

Comment: @Deb Be sure to accept this as the answer if it solved your problem.